# Convention for describing infrastructure: From south & west to north & east

Tags: civil-engineering, standards

When textually describing the extents of infrastructure, such as the roads with red markup in the map below:

[image]

Is there a civil engineering convention for the order/direction in which we would describe the roads?

For example, I'm wondering if the convention is to start at **south & west** and move **north & east**.

1. `Wellington St, from Bathurst St to Portland St`
2. `Portland St, from Wellington St to Stewart St`

Am I remembering correctly? Is that the convention/order/direction that's normally used?

Comment: Start with the major road or the one with the most technical or expensive issues. North etc are understood and used for a reason.

Comment: Their may be regional variation to this.  I work with bridges and culvert for infrastructure and work almost exclusively with roads as a result.  For drawings we lay things out in terms of increasing chainage.  Generally speaking chainage increases from west to east and south to north.  If increasing chainage results in north pointed down on the page you need to talk with the client.

Comment: @ForwardEd Do you want to post that as an answer, or should I?

Comment: I did not feel it was a complete enough answer and was focused more on drawing than on titles for reports or other documents.  As a regional variation, I did a brief stint in the forestry sector,  For their drawings, the convention was when crossing a stream, the water flow pointed to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rigid rule but driven by the purpose of mentioning these streets:

1. Describe a street location and bearing - Willington St. is an east-west street, bounded by Portland ST. on the east, and Bathurst St. on the west.
2. Describe the lot bounded by these streets - "The lot borders Willington St. in the south and bounded between Bathurst St. at the west and Portland St. at the east.", usually, the longer, or major street, is to be addressed first.
3. Given the direction to a destination - Continue driving north on Bathurst St., turn right onto Willington St., then turn left on Portland St.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @ForwardEd:

> Generally speaking, chainage increases from west to east and south to
> north.